# Java: Compare two objects having around 10 or more properties

Tags: java, design-patterns, compare, comparison, mapper

Fetching data from RestUI which comes in com.ow.vo.computer.ApplicationUsage.

Fetching data from Database.

Compare each content as given below

```
public void compare(com.ow.vo.computer.ApplicationUsage src, ApplicationUsage dest) {
    if(!Objects.equals(src.getApplicationItemCost(), dest.getApplicationItemCost())) {
        dest.setApplicationItenCost(src.getApplicationItemCost);
    }
    if(!Objects.equals(src.getAvgUsageTime(), dest.getAvgUsageTime())) {

    }
    if(!Objects.equals(src.getBundleApplicationId(), dest.getBundleApplicationId())) {

    }
    if(!Objects.equals(src.getBundleApplicationName(), dest.getBundleApplicationName())) {

    }
    if(!Objects.equals(src.getDiscoveredDate(), dest.getDiscoveredDate())) {

    }
 .
 . 
 .
```

If any update then only update it into database else do not.

The structure of both src and dest is almost same with difference in date types like Source have String and dest have Date.

Could anyone suggest more elegant way or design pattern to handle this situation in place of comparison each field one by one.

**Business Logic**: (Load chunk from database for 100 records, hit rest api for 100 records. Compare each record 1 by 1( all properties in that 1). If any no difference, Do nothing. If difference Merge it, If new Create record, if not exist in Rest API delete from database too.)

Comment: Can't you map the `src` to your type of `dest` And then apply a simple merge strategy?

Comment: Can't you define an interface or abstract class holding all the common methods/fields?

Comment: Given that setters are a single quick operation, why even bother doing the comparisons? Just call `dest.setX(src.getX())` for every property, regardless of whether or not the destination property already has the same value.

Comment: @Lino: If no differences then we need to ignore this record

Comment: @Seb: I am not sure? Those are database entity on one side and view object on other side

Comment: @Michael: If no differences then we are not gonna insert as i said if any change then update to database else not. So if i set directly how can i check whether to persist or create new or delete any existing.

Comment: It is not clear how you are persisting anything but the simple answer is "update once, at the end", not perform N updates for N changed properties.

Comment: @Michael: Load chunk from database for 100 records, hit rest api for 100 records. Compare each record 1 by 1( all properties in that 1). If any no difference, Do nothing. If difference Merge it, If new in Rest API Create record in DB, if not exist in Rest API delete from database too.

Comment: I think the fastest way to compare the objects is using Merkle Tree Algorithm. In this method, the algorithm calculates the hash of objects and then compares with hash of another object. In this way, the changes can be identified quickly.